# would if faced with the same circumstances

Tags: grammar

*I argue instead that politicians have in fact behaved rationally or at least no differently than their Western counterparts would if faced with the same circumstances.*

I understand the meaning of the clause but I am a little bit puzzled by the usage of the phrase *would if faced*. Is this a sort of inversion? Why is the verb in past tense? Why is *would* and *if* together (*if* and *would* is never good). Can I rewrite this part in this way: *if they (their westen counterparts) faced with the same circumstances.* Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's fine as it is, grammatically as well as for readability. The fact that you "understand the meaning of the clause" shows that.

Comment: "would" here is conditional mood, not past tense, as in "if I were hungry, I would eat."  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#English for a discussion.

Answer (score 6):

> I argue instead that politicians have in fact behaved rationally, or at least no differently than their Western counterparts would if faced with the same circumstances.

This entails a comparative construction. It's quite complicated because it contains several clauses nested within each other. Within the clauses, there is a lot of ellipsis, where various material has been deleted, or omitted because it is recoverable from other clauses. The basic form of the sentence, which we shall call sentence *A*,  is:

- I argue that X

*X* here is a content clause functioning as the complement of *argue*. It in involves a co-ordination with *or*. The form of this clause is:

- politicians have in fact behaved rationally, or at least Y

*Y* is the second co-ordinate in the content clause, *X*. It is basically another content clause joined with the first. The two together function as one big content clause. The form of *Y*, where I've added the missing material is:

- at least [they have behaved] no differently than Z

Notice that *no differently* in the section above has the meaning *not in a different way*. *Y* could therefore be reconstrued as:

- at least they have behaved not in a different way than Z

*Z* here is a comparative clause. It takes the form of a conditional. Notice that what is described in the conditional, is not being talked about as an example of something that is actually going to happen; it is a theoretical situation.  Z therefore takes the form of a conditional where a past tense is used to talk about a hypothetical, imagined, future or present time. Notice that the conditional uses *would* not *will* in the result clause. *Z* can be analyzed as:

- their Western counterparts would [behave in this way], if [they were] faced with the same circumstances [that these politicians are faced with].

We can see from the reconstruted *Z* above, that *Z* is in fact a 'normal' conditional, in the sense that it has two different clauses. It has a result clause ...

- their Western counterparts would [behave in this way]

... and it has an *if*-clause:

- if they were faced with the same circumstances [that these politicians are faced with].

There are two reasons that it looks as though *would* and *if* are occurring in the same clause in the Original Poster's example. The first is that when the result clause comes first and the *if*-clause second, we do not use a comma to separate off the clauses:

- I would kiss that elephant if I could.

Compare that with:

- If I could, I would kiss that elephant.

The second reason is that in comparative clauses, lots of repetition from the first clause is usually avoided. Instead there are large gaps in the sentence which are recovered by the listener from the previous clause. *I can run faster than Bob* means:

- I can run faster than Bob [can run fast].

We don't need to repeat the whole of *can run fast* here because the listener can pick it up from the previous clause. In the Original Poster's sentence the Verb Phrase after *would* has been elided, it's completely missing. Because of this, the next word after *would* is *if*. As we have just said, there is no comma after *if* here, because there is no comma when the *if*-clause comes second. This means that *would* and *if* look as if they run together. They don't!.

Lastly, let us turn to the Original Poster's reformulation of part of this part of the sentence. Notice also that *they were* is missing from the *if*-clause:

- if [they were] faced

We can miss out this material from the subordinate *if*-clause because it has the same subject as the superordinate result clause - namely the Western counterparts. However, we must remove both the subject *they* and the auxiliary passive *were*. Otherwise we need to leave them both in. So in relation to this part of the Original Poster's question, we could rewrite this part of the question as:

- if they (their Western counterparts) **were** faced with the same circumstances.

**Conclusion**

The Original Poster's example involves a remarkable amount of nesting. Buried inside a number of other clauses at the end of the sentence is a comparative clause with the form of a so-called 'remote' conditional. A lot of the material from the conditional is missing, and the *if*-clause has not been moved to the front, as we would often expect. Because the *if*-clause is at the end of the conditional, it is not marked off by a comma. In addition, because the conditional is a comparative clause, much of the material, including the Verb Phrase after *would* is missing. This means that although they are in different clauses, *would* and *if* appear next to each other. A reconstruction of the sentence, including some ellipted material would read so:

> I argue instead that politicians have in fact behaved rationally, or at least they have behaved no differently than their Western counterparts would behave - if they were faced with the same circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

1. The underlying verbal idiom is *face someone with something* = ‘compel someone to confront or deal with something’.
2. *Faced* is not a finite verb but a past participle; here it bears a passive sense, as if there were a preceding *BE*: *(be) faced with* = ‘(be) compelled to confront or deal with something’.
3. An *if* clause whose first verb is *BE* and whose subject is the immediately preceding nominal may delete both of these; thus, *if faced with* is an elliptical form of *they BE faced with*.
4. The verb in the *than* clause has also been reduced by ellipsis: *would* is equivalent to *would BEHAVE*.
5. The capitalized forms *BE* and *BEHAVE* represent constructions which vary, depending on whether the writer intends to depict the hypothetical confrontation as retrospective or prospective. An advantage of the elliptical forms is that they spare the writer the necessity of deciding.

Thus, the sentence may be expanded to:

> I argue instead that politicians have in fact behaved rationally or at least no differently their Western counterparts would ***have behaved*** if ***they had been*** faced with the same circumstances.
>   *OR*
>   ... would ***behave*** if ***they were*** faced ...

Comment: Do you think that maybe it would be *would have behaved if they had been* or *would behave if they were*?

Comment: @Araucaria A very good question, and one I frankly waffled on. You're quite right: I should have picked either *would have ... had been* or *would...were*. I'll roll the dice and pick one.

Comment: Erm, I assumed it the other way in my answer and then got worried that perhaps I'd got it wrong .. . If you want to see waffle by the way have a look at my answer. Oh, +1 btw for a succinct easy to read helpful post ...

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you ... As an ELLer I actually like yours better: it's a paradigmatic ELL answer which doesn't just answer the question but provides guidelines for generalizing the concepts. Do you by any chance teach this stuff?

Comment: Not very much at the mo because I'm trying to do my PhD ... but I used to be a TEFl teacher -and still do for beer money occasionally! I prefer yours, but I'm prone to extended waffling :)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence though grammatically correct, could benefit from some punctuation.

But it is, in my view, awkwardly worded.

If you must insist on it being a single sentence, the following, in my view sounds better: *My argument instead is that politicians have behaved rationally; or at least no differently than would their Western counterparts, if faced with the same circumstances*.

Answer (score 1):

> I argue instead that politicians have in fact behaved rationally or at least no differently than their Western counterparts would if faced with the same circumstances.

The above does not seem to be correct to me, or at least not natural, and you have identified the problem area. I would change it to:

... than their Western counterparts would *have* if faced with ...

Which would have the meaning "would have [behaved]"

With this single addition I find the sentence quite understandable.

Answer (score -1):

The verb (faced) is in past tense because of using conjunctive mood here. "if they (their westen counterparts) faced with the same circumstances" - it's absolutely correct.